# No database selected with RMySQL

Tags: r, rmysql

I'm trying to connect to remote publicly-accessible MySQL server [EnsEMBL](http://www.ensembl.org/info/data/mysql.html) public server using `RMySQL`, but when I try to list the tables, an error occurs:

```
library(RMySQL)

mydb = dbConnect(MySQL(), 
                 user = 'anonymous',
                 port = 5306,
                 host = 'asiadb.ensembl.org')

dbListTables(mydb)

Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) : 
  could not run statement: No database selected
```

Is there a a way to find out the name? Or Am I making a completely different mistake altogether?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to specify the name of the db in the dbConnect call. e.g. :

```
mydb = dbConnect(MySQL(), 
                 user = 'anonymous',
                 port = 5306,
                 host = 'asiadb.ensembl.org',
                 db = 'homo_sapiens_core_83_38')

dbListTables(mydb)
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to find out the names? Do I have to find this out somewhere on their web, or can I get that information by a query from R?

Comment: names of folders on this page http://ftp.ensembl.org/pub/release-83/mysql/ seems to be also names of various db

Comment: Ok, so I have to know the db name beforehand. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 2):

It is weird that `database = 'testdb'` executed with `dbExecute` in `R`

```
db <- dbConnect(RMySQL::MySQL(), 
        user = 'root',
        password = 'pwd123',
        host = 'localhost',
        database = 'testdb'
      )
dbExecute(db, MySQLStatement) # Executed Without Error
```

But when used `dbListTables(db)` showing no databases selected.

Changed `database` into `db` worked as expected

```
db <- dbConnect(RMySQL::MySQL(), 
        user = 'root',
        password = 'pwd123',
        host = 'localhost',
        db = 'testdb'
      )
```